# Trouble with LMI Rescue API and PHP/SOAP

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I'm trying to build a quick tool using LogMeIn's Rescue API. Basically what I want is to be able to enable and disable technicians quickly (even from a mobile device) without having to log into their cumbersome admin panel.

I have figured out how to get their secret password needed for SOAP queries, but I'm having some trouble working with the data when it comes back. The first step in my mini-app is to determine
the current status of the user, so I have a dirty quick test that runs a SOAP client request to their API URL for 2 user (or nodes as they call them). The issues I'm having is with the format of the data when it comes back.

Here is the code of the SOAP request:

```
$authCode = $_SESSION['authCode'];
$user1_status = "";
$user2_status = "";
$soapclient = new SoapClient("https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/api/api.asmx?wsdl");
$iNodeID = $user1; //The value of user1 is defined previous to this bit of code 

$getuserparams = array (
'iNodeID' => $iNodeID,
'sAuthCode' => $authCode
);

$getUserResult = $soapclient->getUser($getuserparams);

.
.
.
//SOAP request for the other user, same stuff
```

Now, if I add `var_export($getUserResult);` after the SOAP client received the data, I get something like this:

> stdClass::__set_state(array( 'getUserResult' => 'getUser_OK', 'oUser' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'iNodeID' => 11028674, 'sName' => 'Tech Name', 'sNick' => 'Tech Name', 'sEmail' => 'tech.name@email.co.uk', 'sSSOID' => 'tech.name@email.co.uk', 'sDescription' => '', 'eType' => 'Technician', 'bAccountHolder' => false, 'hasMobileAddon' => false, 'eStatus' => 'Offline', )), ))

I'm actually only interested in the Technician's name and his status to build a quick table or list with everybody's status. Because of the var_export data, I suspect the stuff that comes back from the SOAP client is an array (I can only assume), so if I try to access it doing the following:

```
$status = var_export($getUserResult["eStatus"], true);
echo $status;
```

I get the following:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\rescue\admin.php on line 53

I have searched around and found a bunch of posts on here talking about the same thing, but I couldn't find anyting referring to pure PHP, most of the stuff was in regards to CMS's like WordPress.

Can you please shed some light on how should I read this data or "make it" into an array to properly need it?

At the moment I'm using a very, very ugly solution by hard coding the names in a table and getting the status as a string by cutting text with substr and str_replace.

In the future, I want to add other features to this thing like reporting and if I can't figure out how to read this data properly, I'm afraid all that is going to be out of the window.

Many thanks for any help you can give me, I'm going nuts over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning you an object rather than an array, so you should try using object notation to access the properties:

```
echo $getUserResult->oUser->sName;
```

This might have been clearer if you used `var_dump` instead of `var_export`, which displays code required to recreate the object, rather than a straight breakdown of the object itself.

Comment: Many many thanks, I have tried var_dump and I can see the full structure now, makes sense. I was first running these tests from a Synology NAS and the result I was getting from var_dump on that server was nothing like the one I'm getting from WAMP. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you have for `$getUserResult` is a `stdClass` object.  What that `__set_state()` tells you is what the currently set properties for the object are. In this case teh information you are interested actually resides in another `stdClass` object set in the `oUser` property.

In order to access the value you need to do:

```
$name = $getUserResult->oUser->sName;

$status = $getUserResult->oUser->eStatus;

etc.
```